# gpg rename encrypted file

Tags: pgp, gnupg

Is there any option to rename the encrypted file in gpg?
For example, when I encrypt a file (eg. file1.txt) I use the command

```
gpg --encrypt --sign --armor -r person@email.com file1.txt
```

What I want is to rename the encrypted file to something like enc-file1.txt

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The [`man` page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gpg), which you really should have checked first, tells me

> **--output** ***file***
>   **-o *file***
>   Write output to *file*.

More information can be found in the [gnupgp documentation](http://www.dewinter.com/gnupg_howto/english/GPGMiniHowto-4.html#ss4.2).

Comment: Note that this option needs to appear before the -e/--encrypt option